# Have Openstack Autopilot installed but unable to launch instances

Tags: juju, openstack

Eventually the openstack installation process on physical servers was done & dusted. I got the dashboard account & address. Now that I try to launch an instance I get this error:

> `Message No valid host was found. There are not enough hosts available.`
>   
>   `Code 500`
>   
>   `Details File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 392, in build_instances context, request_spec, filter_properties) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/conductor/manager.py", line 436, in _schedule_instances hosts = self.scheduler_client.select_destinations(context, spec_obj) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/utils.py", line 372, in wrapped return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/__init__.py", line 51, in select_destinations return self.queryclient.select_destinations(context, spec_obj) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/__init__.py", line 37, in __run_method return getattr(self.instance, __name)(*args, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/client/query.py", line 32, in select_destinations return self.scheduler_rpcapi.select_destinations(context, spec_obj) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nova/scheduler/rpcapi.py", line 121, in select_destinations return cctxt.call(ctxt, 'select_destinations', **msg_args) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/rpc/client.py", line 158, in call retry=self.retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/transport.py", line 90, in _send timeout=timeout, retry=retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 470, in send retry=retry) File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_messaging/_drivers/amqpdriver.py", line 461, in _send raise result`

Would anyone please tell me where should I look for defects and how?. I'm already familiar to get to inner juju environment or deploying juju GUI on machine 0 but what should I do then in this case? Thank you inadvanced.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out to be easier than it seemed. Apparently Landscape created two accounts to access openstack dashboard, admin one which was the one I logged in with & the other one that presumably addressed to as demo user. Using the latter it went smoothly & instance launched.

Comment: The `No valid host was found` error is always a hassle to deal with. The traceback never points to the real problem.